Prove that if $\|f'(x)\| \leq \|x\|$ then $\|f(x)\| \leq \frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2$
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be open and convex, with $0 \in U$. Suppose that $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $||f'(x)|| \leq ||x||$ for every $x \in U$. I have to show that $||f(x)|| \leq \frac{1}{2} ||x||^2$ for every $x \in U$.
I tried using the Mean Value Inequality, or Taylor with Lagrange Remainder, to no avail. I also tried adapting this answer by considering the functions
[
x \mapsto \langle f'(x) y, z \rangle
]
for $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but it did not work as well.

I saw this related post. Can you take a look at it first and see if it answers your question?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132649/if-fx-leq-x-for-al-x-in-u-convex-and-open-with-0-in-u-then-f?rq=1

Hint : For $x \in U$, define $\varphi : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by $\varphi(t)=f(tx)$, and use the fact that $$f(x)=\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\int_0^1 \varphi'(t) dt$$
